# Append Row to Telerik RadGrid from AJAX response as JSON

Tags: asp.net, jquery, telerik

i have here some json request

```
 $.getJSON
       (
          "/Handler/NewUserThenReturnData.ashx",
          {
                data1 : "a",
                data2 : "b"
           },
           function (response) {
                // response is in JSON
           }
        );
```

and a markup

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="radGrid1"> </telerik:RadGrid>
```

my question is how can i insert as new row the **response** in AJAX request to my RadGrid

Thanks in advance.

This is my progress so far..

```
  var $grid = $('#<%=radGrid1.ClientID %> ');

  var _row = $grid.find('tr:last');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to bind the telerik grid on the client side. In that case you can check out the [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-client-side-binding.html), which explains how we can do so.